# alert box jqueryUI

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui

At the moment I am echoing out a simple alert box but I want to echo out `jquery UI` alert box in this code. How can I do this?

```
}else{
      echo '<script language="javascript">';
      echo 'alert("there was an error")';
      echo '</script>';
     }
      }
```

I tried doing this, but its not working

```
 else 
    {
    ?>
        <div id="test">There was en error</div>
            <script type ="text/javascript">
                    $("<div>There was en error</div>").dialog();
                e.preventDefault();
                    </script>

    <?php
}
```

If I can get a little help on how to successfully execute this it would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was able to fix this

```
}else 
        {
            include 'error.php';
        }
```

**error.php**

```
<div style="display:none;" id="upsucess">ERROR Please Try Again </div>

<script type ="text/javascript">
$('#upsucess').dialog({
    title: "Error",
    });
</script>
```

So now it works fine

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `alert("there was an error");` with:

```
$("<div>There was en error</div>").dialog();
```

Comment: @jake123 Your first echo should be like this too: `<script type="text/javascript">`

Comment: `echo '<script language="javascript">';
echo '$("<div>There was en error</div>").dialog()'; 
echo '</script>';`

still not working